# calling a switch statement from main in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
void GetOption(int argc, char * argv[]);
int main() {
  int argc;
  char argv;
  argv = GetOption(argc, argv);
  //argv=GetOption(argv);
  /* Character buffer. */
}
void GetOption(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int m, n, /* Loop counters. */
  l, /* String length. */
  x, /* Exit code. */
  ch;
  for (n = 1; n < argc; n++) /* Scan through args. */ {
    switch ((int) argv[n][0]) /* Check for option character. */ {
      case '-':
      case '/':
        x = 0; /* Bail out if 1. */
        l = strlen(argv[n]);
        for (m = 1; m < l; ++m) /* Scan through options. */ {
          ch = (int) argv[n][m];
          switch (ch) {
            case 'a':
              /* Legal options. */
            case 'A':
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
            case 'x':
            case 'X':
            case 'v':
            case 'V':
            case 'z':
            case 'Z':
            case 'r':
            case 'R':
              printf("Argument = %c called\n", ch);
              break;
            default:
              printf("Illegal option code = %c\n", ch);
              x = 1; /* Not legal option. */
              //exit(1);
              //break;
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to call the switch statement from main but I cant. I specified the cases I wanted to use but is it possible to call the switch cases from main? Should I turn the second function which contains the switch statement into an if statement?

Comment: What do you mean by calling a switch-statement? It's not a function.

Comment: There is something very wrong with main() and GetOption(). Copy/paste error?

Comment: The main definition should have argc, argv as parameters!

Comment: How does `argv=GetOption(argc,argv);` make any sense when `GetOption` is declared as `void`?

Comment: Not likely to parse any options when `argv` and `argc` are local variables in `main()`.

Comment: ..uninitialized local parameters, at that:)  Well, argc anyway.

Comment: @MartinJames: Both are uninitialized, and `argv` is the wrong type!

Comment: @FredLarson well, if it compiled, which it will not, the call to GetOption() would load it.  Please, no more, it's too borken already:)

Comment: There is either a syntax error or a logical error (or both) in approximately every line of code here.

Answer (score 1):

Change the declaration of main to:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {..
```

Then get rid of the two locals:

```
  int argc;
  char argv;
```

Then see how you get on.

Oh - and fix the return types and other stuff posted by @Fred and others:)

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

{

GetOption( argc, argv);

}